# Client Side Form Validation not happening + can't edit form elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I am not able to perform client-side form validation. It's a simple check. I wanna make sure that the passwords are the same. This is the javascript code snippet that I am using for the same.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

  $("#reg-form").submit(function(event)) {
    let $password = $('#password');
    let $confirm = $('#confirmPass');
    let $error = $('#confirmError');

    if ($password.val() === $confirm.val()) {
      return true;
    } else {
      $error.text("Passwords don't match");
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }

})
```

Although, I don't think the problem is in the javascript code because I tried to style some items in the form and that didn't work either so I think it's an HTML issue. However, I can't pinpoint the issue. This is my HTML Code.

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
  <form class="reg-form" id="reg-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="register.php" method="post">

    <div class="form-row">

      <div class="col">
        <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="First Name*" required>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Last Name*" required>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="form-row my-4">
      <div class="col">
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Email*" required>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row my-4">
      <div class="col">
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Password*" required>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row my-4">
      <div class="col">
        <input type="password" name="confirmPass" id="confirmPass" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Confirm Password*" required>
        <small id="confirmError" class="text-danger"></small>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" name="agreement" class="form-check-input" value="" required>
      <label for="agreement" class="form-check-label font-ubuntu text-black-50"> I agree to the Terms and Conditions*</label>
    </div>

    <div class="submit-btn text-center my-5">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning rounded-pill text-dark px-5" name="button">Continue</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

The following is the CSS code that I tried to work with.

```
#reg-form input[type="text"],
#reg-form input[type="email"] {
    border-radius: unset;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid var(--color-border);
    font-family: var(--font-ubuntu);
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some issues with the JavaScript markup, had a few closing brackets missing and closing parentheses declared too early in the code; but your code itself looks like it works with the correct markup on the JS, please see below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#reg-form").submit(function(e) {
    let $password = $('#password');
    let $confirm = $('#confirmPass');
    let $error = $('#confirmError');
    if ($password.val() === $confirm.val()) {
      console.log(true);
      return true
    } else {
    e.preventDefault();
    $error.text("Passwords don't match");
  }
})
})
```

```css
#reg-form input[type="text"],
#reg-form input[type="email"] {
    border-radius: unset;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid var(--color-border);
    font-family: var(--font-ubuntu);
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
  <form class="reg-form" id="reg-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="register.php" method="post">

    <div class="form-row">

      <div class="col">
        <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="First Name*" required>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Last Name*" required>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="form-row my-4">
      <div class="col">
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Email*" required>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row my-4">
      <div class="col">
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Password*" required>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row my-4">
      <div class="col">
        <input type="password" name="confirmPass" id="confirmPass" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Confirm Password*" required>
        <small id="confirmError" class="text-danger"></small>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" name="agreement" class="form-check-input" value="" required>
      <label for="agreement" class="form-check-label font-ubuntu text-black-50"> I agree to the Terms and Conditions*</label>
    </div>

    <div class="submit-btn text-center my-5">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning rounded-pill text-dark px-5" name="button">Continue</button>
    </div>
  </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. While the password validation is now happening, I am running into another issue. The form submission doesn't take place any more. When I press continue, the form doesn't reload to a new page and stays the same way.

Comment: Hello, I've just updated the answer you can move the `preventDefault()` method into the else statment if the validation fails; otherwise default behavior will persist.

Comment: Yes, that actually makes sense. I will just test it with this change but I think this should work. Thanks!